# how to rename a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to remove the `_id` prefix the foreign key?
New table. Two models `Order` and `Product`

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :delivery, :class_name => "Order"
end
```

Make in the `products` table `t.integer :delivery, index: true`

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Order(#85313090) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Fixnum(#73138750)
```

How to fix?

Comment: It may seem like a good idea to use a non-standard foreign key name, but it will bite you in the future. Strongly consider using the Rails Way.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the possibilities of fighting with rails when doing something like this, I'd simply override the `delivery=(value)` method. e.g.:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :delivery, :class_name => "Order"

  def delivery=(id)
    delivery_id = id
  end
end
```

In effect, this will prevent assigning objects to the association. Other methods, e.g. `build_delivery` and `delivery` will still be present and could be overwritten as well but as @moveson has already pointed out, striving from the rails way will typically cause pain later on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `foreign_key` name in models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, foreign_key: "delivery"
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :delivery, :class_name => "Order", foreign_key: "delivery"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The good answer is you don't. You can alias associations by using the foreign key and class_name options:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, foreign_key: "delivery_id"
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :delivery, class_name: "Order"
end
```

But the `_id` suffix is a really good convention as it makes very easy to understand the schema as its almost overly apparent which columns are foreign key columns. And conventions are what makes Rails awesome.

There is no good reason to skirt it unless you have a crappy legacy application.